# scroll to a div when scrolling, and scroll to top when div disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, scrollto

I have 2 divs on my webpage. first div is "#pattern" (red one), and second on is "#projets".(blue one)

when use scrolls for the first time, the window scrolls automaticaly to the the second div "#projets". I'm using jquery scroll-To plugin.
it works nice, even if when the users scroll with a large amount of scroll there could be on offset from the "#projets" div... If someone has an idea to correct this would be nice, but that's not my main trouble...

Now i'm trying to scroll back to the top of the page ("#pattern" div) as soon as "#pattern" div reappears when scrolling, the red one. so basically it should be as soon as the offset from the top of my screen of my div "#projets" is supperior to 1.

I've tried so many solutions without results, using flags, multiple conditions... it can be the same kind of thing as on this page, but user should be abble to scroll freely inside the page, not scrolling from hash to hash :

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

here is my html :

```
<div id="pattern"></div>
<div id="projets"></div>
```

my css :

```
#pattern {
    height:300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red
}

#projets {
    height:800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:blue
}
```

and my jquery :

```
var flag=0 ;

$(window).on('scroll',function(){   

var top_projets_position = $("#projets").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

    if((flag==0) && $(window).scrollTop()>1){ 
        $(window).scrollTo('#projets', 500);
        flag=1;
    }    

        if($(window).scrollTop()==0){ 
        flag=0;
    }   

});
```

here is jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/jdf9q0sv/

hope someone can help me with this, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, maybe a wrong method ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to track 3 things:

1. The scroll direction occurs.
2. The area you are currently viewing.
3. If scroll animation is currently happening (we need to wait until it's done, or problems will occur).

http://jsfiddle.net/vx69t5Lt/

```
var prev_scroll = 0;           // <-- to determine direction of scrolling
var current_view ="#pattern";  // <-- to determine what element we are viewing
var allowed = true;            // <-- to prevent scrolling confusion during animation

var top_projets_position = $("#projets").offset().top + 1;

$(window).on('scroll',function(){ 
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(current_scroll < top_projets_position && current_view=="#projets" && current_scroll < prev_scroll){
        scrollToTarget("#pattern");
    }
    if($(window).height() + current_scroll > top_projets_position && current_view=="#pattern" && current_scroll > prev_scroll){
         scrollToTarget("#projets");
    }

    prev_scroll = current_scroll;
});

function scrollToTarget(selector){
    if(allowed){
        allowed = false;
        $(window).scrollTo(selector, {
            'duration':500, 
            'onAfter': function(){ allowed = true;  current_view = selector;}
        });
    }
}
```

This is just a quick solution based on your original code. A better solution would be to do something more Object Oriented (OOP) and track values in an object. Perhaps take an array of elements on object creation, grab all the boundaries and use the boundaries in your scroll handler to determine when to scroll to the next div.